# How to do the toArray method in a binary-search-tree in java?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I need to write a method, toArray, that puts the items of a binary search tree into an array. The array must be in ascending order. Right now, I'm working on the tree nodes, and will later add it into the BSTree.

```
public class TreeNode
{
    Number value; 
    TreeNode left; 
    TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(Number value)
    {
        this.value=value;
    }
    public Number[] toArray()
    {
        //???
    }
}
```

I know what I need to do, but I am not sure how to code it. I can recursively toArray the left and the right of the tree. Afterward I need to create a bigger array and copy the items into it and then return the new, bigger array. There must also be a termination condition of having no children, in the event of which I must make an array of length 1 and then put value in it.

Comment: Build an `ArrayList` initially, because they're easier to concatenate.  Do the conversion to the array as the last step.

Comment: This problem is best solved by recursion. 1) add elements of `left`, 2) add `value`, 3) add elements of `right` to the resulting `ArrayList`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem see my comment on the solution below as to why it is non-optimal to use an ArrayList

Comment: @ControlAltDel You are welcome to post an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use recursion to build your array.  As @Dawood commented, it would be easier to first add your sorted numbers from the tree to an `ArrayList`, then convert it to a formal array later.  The basic logic in the recursion is that, for each node, we add all the numbers on the left first, then we add the node's particular value, then we add all the numbers on the right.  If we consider the following binary tree, this makes sense:

```
     5
   /   \
  2     7
 / \   / \
1   3 6   8
```

The method below would traverse down the left, add `1`, then `2`, `3`, `5`, followed by the right side of the tree.  In order for this approach to make any sense, it assumes the tree is sorted.  If the tree were not sorted, then it woulnd't be very useful for searching.

```
public void add(TreeNode node, List<Number> list) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }

    add(node.getLeft(), list);
    list.add(node.getValue());
    add(node.getRight(), list);

    return;
}

public Number[] toArray(TreeNode head) {
    List<Number> list = new ArrayList<>();
    add(head, list);

    Number[] array = new Number[list.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
        array[i] = list.get(i);
    }

    return array;
}
```

Comment: You could use the `toArray` method of the `List` interface as the last step.

Comment: The conversation from an ArrayList to a Number[] makes this two pass anyway. So better to create a size() method that counts the number of values, and use that method to initiate the size of the array

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but what can I change the List<Number> to because it won't compile.

Comment: @JasonDescartes Post the error message you are getting.  I haven't tested this code, but I believe it to be (nearly) correct.